# SuperCat can't find configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, colors

Recently I've downloaded SuperCat but I can't get it to work. There is always a message:

```
can't find a config file
```

Although I've created it in `~/.spcrc/spcrc`.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: did you even look into the ~/.spcrc/ directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your config file is incomplete. The associated file type is missing.

Here is an excerpt from https://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005732

> All rules for colorizing text are stored in files with names of the
>   form spcrc-ext, where "ext" is the file type. These files are stored
>   in the configured "system directory" or else your private ~/.spcrc
>   directory. For example, the rules for a C source code file in spcrc-c
>   might look like:

```
#  HTML COLOR NAME   COL A N T STRING or REGULAR EXPRESSION
#################### ### # # # ################################################################
Red                  red b     ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[[:space:]]*\(
Brown                yel b     (while|for|if|switch|main|return)[[:space:]]*\(
Brown                yel b     (else)
Cyan                 cya b     [[:space:]]*(include)
Green                grn       (do)[[:space:]]*\{
Cyan                 cya       (case|return|default)
Green                grn       (break|continue)[[:space:]]*;
Magenta              mag       (int|char|short|float|double|long|unsigned)[[:space:]]
Blue                 blu b     [^[:alnum:]_]([[:digit:]]+)
Brown                yel       "(.*)"
Brown                yel       <(.*)>
Magenta              mag     c :;
```